# QuadTree find neighbor

Tags: algorithm, quadtree

I'm searching for a algorithm to find neighbors of a quadtree, in the example image, I got the red node, how to find the blue nodes. Any ideas?

[image: example]

Comment: The Url doesnt work..

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20837530/quadtree-nearest-neighbour-algorithm

Comment: As a note, in case you do this for finding nearest neighbors and you have to find a lot of nearest neighbors you might find a CoverTree more suited for your task than a Quadtree. Especially if you have to do stuff like k-neighbors or similar. Nevermind if you use this for other purposes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are some known algorithms. Check them out.

1. [Kunio Aizawa et al.](http://www.lcad.icmc.usp.br/%7Ejbatista/procimg/quadtree_neighbours.pdf) - Constant Time Neighbor Finding in Quadtrees: An Experimental Result
2. [Kasturi Varadarajan](http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/%7Ekvaradar/sp2012/daa/ann.pdf) - All Nearest Neighbours via Quadtrees
3. [Robert Yoder, Peter Bloniarz](http://web.archive.org/web/20120907211934/http://ww1.ucmss.com/books/LFS/CSREA2006/MSV4517.pdf) - A Practical Algorithm for Computing Neighbors in Quadtrees, Octrees, and Hyperoctrees

Comment: Realize this was a while ago - but do you happen to remember the name or anything of the linked article? As the link no-longer works!

Comment: I should have put the names in my answer in the first place. My bad. The link should work now. But the point is - it's really easy to google such algorithms.

Comment: And google finds your answer! So this post is a good location to have the relevant links. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If your language has good support for arrays and you can choose the representation of your tree, then this turns out to be *much* simpler than various papers suggest.

Trick is to represent the parent-child relationship as a vector:

```py
def neighbour(tree, node, direction):
    """Finds the neighbour of a node in an adaptive quadtree or it's D-dimensional
    generalization (orthantree?).

    Be very careful with indexing when implementing this. Because it indexes  
    physical space with arrays, sometimes you need to think of coords in terms
    of Euclidean coords, and other times in terms of array coords.

    Args:
        tree: an object holding a bunch of node attributes, indexed by node:
            * `parent`, an (N,)-array of integers. The `n`th element gives the 
               index of `n`'s parent. The parent of the root is -1.
            * `children`, an ((N,) + (2,)*D)-array of integers. The `n`th slice 
               gives the indices of `n`'s children. The bottom-left child of node 3
               in a quadtree would be (3, 0, 0). 
            * `descent`, an (N, D)-array with elements from {-1, +1}. The `n`th
               row gives which direction node `n` lies in compared to its parent.
               For example, the left-bottom quadrant in a quadtree would be `(-1, -1)`.
            * `terminal`, an (N,)-array of booleans. The `n`th element is True
               if node `n` is a leaf.
        node: an integer, the index of the node you want to find the neighbour of.
        direction: a (D,)-array with elements from {-1, +1}

    Returns:
        An integer giving the index of the neighbouring node, or -1 if it doesn't 
        exist.
    """
    direction = np.asarray(direction)

    # Ascend to the common ancestor
    neighbour_descents = []
    while True:
        if (direction == 0).all() or node < 0:
            break
        node_descent = tree.descent[node]
        neighbour_descent = node_descent*(1 - 2*abs(direction))
        neighbour_descents.append(neighbour_descent)

        direction = ((node_descent + direction)/2).astype(int)
        node = tree.parent[node]

    # Descend to the neighbour 
    for neighbour_descent in neighbour_descents[::-1]:
        if tree.terminal[node] or node < 0:
            break
        node = tree.children[(node, *(neighbour_descent.T + 1)//2)]

    return node
```

It supports bitrees (?), quadtrees, octrees, and general N-dimensional trees (hyperoctree? orthantree?). It also supports any direction - cardinal or diagonal. Finally, it's really easy to vectorize.

Inspiration was the FSM-based approach from Yoder that @torvin posted, plus a requirement this work for any number of dimensions.

[There's test and demo code here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1FQiP0hXhAYMHJtIwxFc8zchlwtP7CiDe).