# How to ensure minimum euclidean distance in a list of tuples

Tags: python

I have an extremely large list of coordinates in the form of a list of tuples.

```
data = [(1,1),(1,11),(1,21),(11,1),(21,1),(11,11),(11,21),(21,11),(21,21),(1,2),(2,1)]
```

The list of tuple is actually being formed by a for loop with an append command like so:

```
data = []
    for i in source: # where i a tuple of form (x,y)
        data.append(i)
```

Is there an approach to ensure euclidean distance between all tuples is above a certain threshold? In this example there is a very small distance between (1,1),(1,2),(2,1). In this scenario I would like to keep only one of the 3 tuples. Resulting in either one of these new list of tuples:

```
data = [(1,1),(1,11),(1,21),(11,1),(21,1),(11,11),(11,21),(21,11),(21,21)]
data = [(2,1),(1,11),(1,21),(11,1),(21,1),(11,11),(11,21),(21,11),(21,21)]
data = [(1,2),(1,11),(1,21),(11,1),(21,1),(11,11),(11,21),(21,11),(21,21)]
```

I have a brute force algorithm that iterates through the list but there should be a more elegant way or quicker way to do this? Or is there any other methods to speed up this operation? I am expecting lists of ~70k up to 500k tuples.

My method:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean
data = [(1,1),(1,11),(1,21),(11,1),(21,1),(11,11),(11,21),(21,11),(21,21),(1,2),(2,1)]
new_data = []
while len(data) >0:
    
    check = data.pop()
    flag = True
    for i in data:
         if euclidean(check,i) < 5:
              flag = False
              break
         else:
              pass
    if flag == True:
        new_data.append(check)
    else:
        flag = True
```

Additional points:
Although the list of tuples is coming from some iterative function, the order of tuples is uncertain.
Actual number of tuples is unknown until end of for loop.
I would rather avoid multiprocessing/multithreading for speed up in this scenario.
If necessary I can put up some timings but I dont think its necessary.
The solution I have right now is time O(n(n-1)/2) and space complexity of O(n) I think so any improvement would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can organize your 2D data/tuples using a [Quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree).

> Quadtrees are the two-dimensional analog of octrees and are most often used to partition a two-dimensional space by recursively subdividing it into four quadrants or regions.

Comment: Hi Alex, I am not really understanding how Quadtrees will help. From what I can gather, that would mean as I get points, it builds a point-node with some defined width/height...and for every point I check if it exists in any point-node area and creates a new node if it doesnt exist? A code example of how you mean to apply a Quadtree would be most appreciated.

Comment: If you organize your points in a quad-tree, it's fast to find the nearest neighbour. Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32412107/quadtree-find-neighbor

Comment: Ah that explains it quite well. Thanks for the answer. Will accept as valid later. If there are newer solutions would be interesting as well.

Comment: Thanks. Your question is interesting and has potential for fruitful answers, I do hope that more people answer with their ideas.

Answer (score 0):

you can use numpy try this :

```
import numpy as np

data = [(1,1),(1,11),(1,21),(11,1),(21,1),(11,11),(11,21),(21,11),(21,21),(1,2),(2,1)]
start_time = time.time()
#transform to numpy array
a = np.array(data)
subs = a[:,None] - a
#calculate ecludien distance between all element
dist=np.sqrt(np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ij',subs,subs))
#replace 0 to 5 because distance distance between identic element will be 0
dist=np.where(dist == 0, 5, dist)
#select element where distance sup to 5
dist_bool=[dist[:,0] < 5]
#select element where distance sup to 5 are false 
a=a[dist_bool[0] == False]
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))#got --- 0.00020575523376464844 seconds ---
```

when we compare to your soltion :

```
start_time = time.time()
new_data = []
while len(data) >0:
    check = data.pop()
    flag = True
    for i in data:
         if euclidean(check,i) < 5:
              flag = False
              break
         else:
              pass
    if flag == True:
        new_data.append(check)
    else:
        flag = True
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))# got ---0.001013040542602539 seconds ---
```

Comment: Is this answer helped you ?

Comment: Hi its an interesting solution. Thanks for the input.

Comment: you can optimize it more if u r inseresting