# QuadTree Neighbours defining

Tags: data-structures, compression, nearest-neighbor, quadtree, neighbours

Hi i'd like to find all the neoghbours of node in a quadTree that has size up to 2^(10^9) per edge and up to 10^6 nodes in total.

I have seen this post [Quadtree Nearest Neighbour Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20837530/quadtree-nearest-neighbour-algorithm)

I had an idea with putting into some ordered set the centers of each node during dfs and them during postorder in dfs defining whether the center of some node has overlap. The problem is that with comparing such huge numbers idk how to even store the bounds.

language is c++

How would you try to store such points and bounds?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, to solution was to scale the quadtree. With the limit of 10^6 nodes totally its easy to do. As we can imagine it as 10^3 x 10^3 tile map.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're going to get anywhere with this, as that's a number with 300 million digits. You didn't specify the language, but many have arbitrary-precision integer arithmetic that can handle numbers like that. Some examples are Python natively and the [GMP package](https://gmplib.org/) for C/C++.

Here is a much smaller example than yours in Python:

```
Python 3.8.2 (default, Oct  2 2020, 10:45:42) 
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.27)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 2**10000
19950631168807583848837421626835850838234968318861924548520089498529438830221946631919961684036194597899331129423209124271556491349413781117593785932096323957855730046793794526765246551266059895520550086918193311542508608460618104685509074866089624888090489894838009253941633257850621568309473902556912388065225096643874441046759871626985453222868538161694315775629640762836880760732228535091641476183956381458969463899410840960536267821064621427333394036525565649530603142680234969400335934316651459297773279665775606172582031407994198179607378245683762280037302885487251900834464581454650557929601414833921615734588139257095379769119277800826957735674444123062018757836325502728323789270710373802866393031428133241401624195671690574061419654342324638801248856147305207431992259611796250130992860241708340807605932320161268492288496255841312844061536738951487114256315111089745514203313820202931640957596464756010405845841566072044962867016515061920631004186422275908670900574606417856951911456055068251250406007519842261898059237118054444788072906395242548339221982707404473162376760846613033778706039803413197133493654622700563169937455508241780972810983291314403571877524768509857276937926433221599399876886660808368837838027643282775172273657572744784112294389733810861607423253291974813120197604178281965697475898164531258434135959862784130128185406283476649088690521047580882615823961985770122407044330583075869039319604603404973156583208672105913300903752823415539745394397715257455290510212310947321610753474825740775273986348298498340756937955646638621874569499279016572103701364433135817214311791398222983845847334440270964182851005072927748364550578634501100852987812389473928699540834346158807043959118985815145779177143619698728131459483783202081474982171858011389071228250905826817436220577475921417653715687725614904582904992461028630081535583308130101987675856234343538955409175623400844887526162643568648833519463720377293240094456246923254350400678027273837755376406726898636241037491410966718557050759098100246789880178271925953381282421954028302759408448955014676668389697996886241636313376393903373455801407636741877711055384225739499110186468219696581651485130494222369947714763069155468217682876200362777257723781365331611196811280792669481887201298643660768551639860534602297871557517947385246369446923087894265948217008051120322365496288169035739121368338393591756418733850510970271613915439590991598154654417336311656936031122249937969999226781732358023111862644575299135758175008199839236284615249881088960232244362173771618086357015468484058622329792853875623486556440536962622018963571028812361567512543338303270029097668650568557157505516727518899194129711337690149916181315171544007728650573189557450920330185304847113818315407324053319038462084036421763703911550639789000742853672196280903477974533320468368795868580237952218629120080742819551317948157624448298518461509704888027274721574688131594750409732115080498190455803416826949787141316063210686391511681774304792596709376
>>>
```

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is with the comparing these numbers with 300 milion digits are too big to sort or compare when there are 1mln of them